# error de acceso denegado al conectar a mysql desde nod.js

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

Tengo el siguiente error: `ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)` mi código es el siguiente:

aquí los datos de configuración de la base de datos:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool ( { 
  host: process.env.DB_HOST, 
  user: process.env.DB_USER, 
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT, 
  database: process.env.DB_NAME 
} ) ;

exports.pool = pool;
```

aquí me conecto a la base de datos y hago la consulta:

```js
//const mysql = require('mysql');
const bd = require('../db').pool;
require('dotenv').config();


 
 const getAll =  () => {
 console.log('User:'+process.env.DB_USER)
 console.log('Pass:'+process.env.DB_PASS)
 console.log('Port:'+process.env.DB_PORT)


 //console.log('process.env.DB_HOST: ',process.env.DB_PASS);
 bd.getConnection(function(err,conn){
  if(err) throw err
  conn.query('SELECT * FROM usuario', function(error,results,fields){
   console.log('todo OK-2');
   if(error) throw error;
   console.log('The solution is: ', results[0]);
   


  });


 });
};

module.exports = { getAll: getAll }
```

aquí esta una captura del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que he probado? leí que hay una pregunta similar aquí en el foro, así que intenté creando un nuevo usuario con todos los privilegios pero el error persiste, anteriormente la clave de root era una cadena vacía, intenté cambiando la clave y tampoco funcionó. que será lo que pasa? ya no se que mas intentar. de tanto probar cosas el mysql no quería iniciar (uso XAMPP), así que tuve que reinstalarlo. Gracias de antemano al que pueda ayudarme.

[[ EDITADO ]]

Este es mi archivo .env:

```
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=
DB_PORT=3306
DB_NAME=bdbancoimagenes
```

y hago el require del .env en el server.js solament, como lo hacen en el tutorial.

Comment: Al parecer es la configuracion de tu conexion a la base de datos, tu usuario creeria yo que esta erroneo

Comment: pero está bien, de hecho, mande a imprimir los valores del usuario y la contraseña con un console.log y son los correctos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta ejecutar el comando

```
DB_USER=tuUsuario DB_PASS=tuPass node-dev server.js
```

Es evidente que por algún lado no están llegando ni user ni pass al momento de crear la conexión.

Comment: Disculpa, eso lo ejecuto en la terminal donde corro el servidor de node? lo estoy colocando y dice queDB_USER no se reconoce como un comando válido.

Comment: es verdad, en Windows no funciona así
prueba antes de correr node-dev server.js
hacer `set DB_USER=tuuser` y lo mismo para DB_PASS

Comment: amigo acabo de probar y si funcionó. porque así si funciona? no entiendo que pasa ahí. también tuve que setear el puerto y el nombre de la base de datos.

Comment: acabo de editar mi pregunta para que veas como tengo el archivo .env y donde hago el require de dicho archivo.

Comment: quizá en lugar de usar process.env usar solo dotenv para leer esos valores?

Comment: Cómo sería? Y por qué hacerlo así?  Lo que hice fue agregar el requiere de dontenv en el archivo donde está el pool y funciona, pero no entiendo xq así si funciona. Anteriormente lo tenía en el server.js.

Comment: ya entiendo. mueve la línea require('dotenv').config() a tu archivo db.js, al principio

lo que veo en el código actual es que estás llamando a dotenv luego de llamar a ese archivo ,por lo tanto en ese archivo process.env todavía no fue populado por dotenv

Comment: Ok. uno última pregunta. las variables de entorno son accesibles únicamente desde el archivo donde hago el require('dotenv').config(); ?  por ejemplo, tengo archivo1.js y archivo2.js , tendría que hacer un require('dotenv').config(); en esos dos archivos para poder acceder a las variables de entorno?

Comment: es probable que no necesites hacerlo una y otra vez, pero sí es importante que lo hayas hecho _antes_ de querer acceder a process.env , esto es lo que pasaba en db.js , se ejecutaba antes que dotenv.config()